# wkhtmltopdf not working after server migration

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I'm changing server and I'm in the process of migrating the content, using a cloned copy. I'm checking that everything works.

But the generation of a pdf using wkhtmltopdf and the snappy wrapper does not work. It seems to create a pdf, but when trying to open it says:

> Unable to open document "file:///home/rosamunda/Desktop/file.pdf".
> File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported.

Here's the file in question:

```
  error_reporting();
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
$snappy->setBinary('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```

**The page is completely blank, no errors in the error log.**

**PHP version:** PHP-FPM 8.2.17 (remi-safe).

**OpenSSL version:** 1.1.1k FIPS 25 Mar 2021

**Multibyte decoding support using mbstring:** Enabled

Any insight is greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Do you think that a file which begins with `hola mundo` is a valid PDF?

Comment: "no errors in the error log" -- because you're using `echo` before `header()`, this code should log a "headers already sent" warning. Perhaps your error level is set too low. Calling `error_reporting()` without any arguments doesn't do anything, try setting it to `E_ALL` for debugging.

Comment: "when trying to open it says" - what does that mean? What **exactly** does the resulting file contain?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The "Hola Mundo" was one of the tests that I added to see if the page printed anything at least on the screen. Thanks for mentioning it, I deleted it and forgot to delete it here.

Comment: Now the example reflects exactly the file that I'm using.
When I access the file (demo.php) I get from the browser a prompt saying if I want to open or download a pdf file. If I download it I get the error mentioned in the question, if I select open, it shows a blank screen.

Comment: From the server’s perspective there’s should be no difference between “open” and “download”, at least in this situation. Try downloading the file and opening it with a text editor.

Comment: Also, have you tried running wkhtmltopdf from the CLI?

Comment: I think wkhtmltopdf is not installed!! "The exit status code '127' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory" When opening the file in a normal text editor! It didn't ocurr to me (doh!) that I could open it in a text editor and check for error messages inside! Thanks!

Comment: I ask for the server's admins to install it, and the error is still there.

Comment: You asked the server admins to install it, and you still have an error? Does a binary at that path exist?

Comment: Yes, it's on .../usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: When you manually run that command from the CLI, do you get output?